# Get origin of a Ng-click on buttons?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to reset background-colors (bgNeutral) of all my buttons, except the only one who are solicited (who have to switch in "bgSelected"):

```
<button ng-class="button1" ng-click="addActifOnMe($1)" class="bgSelected"></button>
<button ng-class="button2" ng-click="addActifOnMe($2)" class="bgNeutral"></button>
<button ng-class="button3" ng-click="addActifOnMe($3)" class="bgNeutral"></button>
```

This is my .js:

```
app.controller("angularController", function ($scope) {
    $scope.button1 = "bgSelected";

    $scope.addActifOnMe = function (1) {
        $scope.button2 = "bgNeutral";
        $scope.button3 = "bgNeutral";
        $scope.button1 = "bgSelected";
    };

    $scope.addActifOnMe = function (2) {
        $scope.button1 = "bgNeutral";
        $scope.button3 = "bgNeutral";
        $scope.button2 = "bgSelected";
    };

    $scope.addActifOnMe = function (3) {
        $scope.button1 = "bgNeutral";
        $scope.button2 = "bgNeutral";
        $scope.button3 = "bgSelected";
    };
});
```

CSS can be something like that:

```
.bgSelected{
background-color: red;
}

.bgNeutral{
background-color: blue;
}
```

But actually this, doesn't work... I'm trying to use ngClick with $event in my function. Someone have a better way for doing that ?

Thank you ! Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using a variable `selectedButton` in your controller to track which button is selected.

```
<button class="neutral" ng-class="{selected: todoList.selectedButton === 1}" ng-click="todoList.select(1)">button 1</button>
<button class="neutral" ng-class="{selected: todoList.selectedButton === 2}" ng-click="todoList.select(2)">button 2</button>
<button class="neutral" ng-class="{selected: todoList.selectedButton === 3}" ng-click="todoList.select(3)">button 3</button>
```

controller:

```
angular.module('todoApp', [])
    .controller('TodoListController', function() {
        var todoList = this;
        todoList.selectedButton = 1;

        todoList.select = function(buttonNumber) {
            todoList.selectedButton = buttonNumber;
        }
    });
```

[Here's a plunker to demonstrate this working](https://plnkr.co/edit/nLB4etFzq2JwU1Kw4Dsx?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for this super complete answer ! It's working perfectly.